# How to get value an array laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I just want to ask, how do I get the value of this code with laravel 4?

```
$auth = DB::select(
    'SELECT auth FROM users WHERE username like ?'
    , array($username)
);
```

When I display the result of the code, its echoing "Array" and it always redirecting the user to 'anotherpage' I'm actually doing like:

```
if (Auth::attempt($userdata))
{
    if ($auth==0)
    {
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    elseif ($auth==1)
    {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    } 
    else 
    {
        return Redirect::to('anotherpage');
    }
}
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: It is most likely that this is not specific to Laravel-4. Please be more specific where exactly your problem is. What does qualify as *the value of this code*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why are you authenticating the user twice through Auth class and manual SELECT query? `Auth::attempt` is enough. [Read it here.](http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users)

Anyway, assuming you really wanna do it that way, your code isn't working properly because you're assigning `$auth` to 0 within the `if` statement; so this :

```
if($auth = 0)
```

Is basically this:

```
if(0) //Which is always false
```

So, i'd change the if statement to :

```
if($auth == 0)
```

### Your final code **should** look like this:

```
if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) 
{
  $auth = DB::table('users')->where('username', '=', $username)->first()->auth;//Don't use "LIKE" as it may cause huge security issues.
  if($auth == 0) {
        return Redirect::to('home');
  }
  else if($auth == 1) {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
  }
  else {
        return Redirect::to('anotherpage');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the value of 'Auth' column of the user who logged in. For example, when the user logged in. it will first authenticate and afterwards tell what page the user will go using `if($auth==0`.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you try to echo an array. Use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) instead. It prints a readable output of the contents of an array (or a variable):

```
$myArray = DB::select('SELECT auth FROM users WHERE username like ?', array($username));
print_r($myArray);
```

That way, you'll see the contents of the array, and you can then display the specific item.

Enclosing it in `<pre>` tags will make the output, even more readable:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or simply:

```
echo '<pre>', print_r($myArray), '</pre>';
```

Comment: This works but it's not working when I put it in an if statement sir.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the query builder wrong.  Try this:

```
$auth = DB::table('users')->select('auth')->where('username', 'LIKE', $username)->get();
dd($auth);
```